# Email User that broke build pipeline in teamcity

Tags: dependencies, teamcity, artifacts

We have setup [teamcity build chain](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/03/teamcity-take-on-build-pipelines/).
We also have email notification setup, which notifies the user who has broken the build.

However it does not work for chained builds.
Lets Say we have Project A, and project B.
User committed some change in Project A.
Project A build is now successful and thus triggers Project B.
Project B fails. At this step i want to notify build breaker who has commited the change in project A.

This can be tracked manually, but very easily overlooked, unless someone is really checking Project B.
How can this be automated in teamcity?

Comment: Does B have a snapshot dependency on A?

Comment: no, it is artifact dependency.

Answer (score 1):

1. Link A & B with a snapshot dependency.
2. In B's *Version Control Settings*, check *Show changes from snapshot dependencies*.

That way, when John makes a (breaking) change in A, builds A (which passes), TeamCity triggers B (which fails), the failing build of B will also "contain" John's commit in A. Thus, John will be notified (assuming reasonable notification rules).